# G-sync with a Displayport to DVI adapter

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, dvi, nvidia-graphics-card

So I bought two AOCG2460PG screens for my new setup (nVidia GTX 780 SLI) but came across a slight oversight; I found that the monitors only support Displayport and that there's only one Displayport contact per GPU, so I can only use one monitor, for now (since only the master card in an SLI setup can connect to the monitor).

Now, I've considered getting a Displayport to DVI adapter, easy to get at the nearest tech store, which'll let me plug both monitors into the master card, but I keep hearing that G-sync only works with Displayport, does this matter when I use an adapter? I assume that quality, otherwise, is not a particular concern.

The other option for me, if an adapter doesn't work, is to get a Displayport MST hub, the same questions as above applies to this, too.

Comment: To bad that these monitors only have one DP input port. Otherwise you would be able to link from one monitor to the next. (MST). They leaves you with four solutions:
1) Another 780 card (even my 760 ships with 3 DP outs),  
2) One other monitor with DP out (Desktop - New Mon -- old mon). 
3) An active convertor from DVI (which will limit your resolution to 2560x1440, maybe not a problem today but a limit in the future). 
4) A DP hub (About 100 Eur, so not all that much more than an active convertor)

Note that DP is quite different from DVI and that you can not use a simple 'cable' as adaptor.

Comment: Easiest choice would be [this](http://www.amazon.com/Club-CSV-5300-SenseVision-DisplayPort-3xDisplayPort/dp/B00CD2632M)